# How to limit access to resources/tables in Dynamo to a particular environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Suppose there are multiple tables in one dynamo instance for multiple environment.

I need like tables meant for alpha environment can be accessed by alpha

environment only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to DynamoDB in AWS console and selecting table > Access Control you can see *Attach policy instructions*. It says:

1. Go to the IAM console to attach this policy.
2. In the IAM console, click Roles, and then click Create New Role.
3. Enter a name for the role and click Continue.
4. In the Select Role Type pane, choose Role for Web Identity Provider Access and click Select.
5. Enter your Identity Provider and Application ID, and click Continue.
6. Verify that the trust policy document is correct, and click Continue.
7. In the Set Permissions pane, choose Custom Policy and click Select.
8. Enter a name for the policy, and then copy and paste the above policy into the Policy Document field. When you have done this, click Continue.
9. On the Review pane, click Create Role.

Comment: Thanks @Justinas. What is the application id in 5 step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/) users with proper policy permissions for that. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DynamoDBListTables",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:ListTables",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacityOfferings"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DynamoDBAllActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:677412391455:table/demo"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, if i am going to give only this resource it is not accessable.

Comment: Have you attached this policy to your desired IAM user/group? Did you replace the `{ }` placeholders with the correct values?

Comment: Yes i have attached this policy to a user and yes i have replaced the {} with correct values. Only now there is one policy which is mine with that user.

Comment: There were 10 tables, i had to access only one table , but no one is accessible now. Please suggest.

Comment: You can add as many resources as you wish (see my updated answer). Or, you could just use wildcards for resources that have common prefixes, e.g., `arn:aws:dynamodb:{REGION}:{ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:table/Dev*`

Comment: I created new user and one and only one this policy is attached with this user, do i need to attached other policy to this user? As i am unable to access even single table of them. Please suggest once more.

Comment: Maybe you have a syntax error in the policy document. Can you share that policy with us?

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DynamoDBFillAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:677412391455:table/demo"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Policy is valid. Is this user trying to access the table programmatically (SDK) or from the management console through the browser? In case of programmatic access, did you create an `access key` for the user?

Comment: In case of Management Console access, you'll need to add additional permissions to list the tables. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot khalid, Now i want to perform read, write and update operation on this table but it is only readable. How to give permission of write and update.

Comment: The user already has full access on the `demo` table. Just select the table from the console and go to the `Items' tab. You'll be able to update the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Khalid.